# rmagick installation issue on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rmagick

I'm trying to install `rmagick 2.13.1` for my legacy rails application on Ubuntu 16.04. I get following error when I do `bundle install`:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'
```

Following are the content of `mkmf.log`

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_executable: checking for gcc... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_executable: checking for Magick-config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... -------------------- yes

--------------------

checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -I/usr/include/GraphicsMagick  -fopenmp -Wall -g -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -pthread conftest.c  -L. -L/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -Wl,-R/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/X11    -lGraphicsMagick -ljbig -lwebp -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljasper -ljpeg -lpng12 -lwmflite -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread  -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/home/uping/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker is complaining that you don't have [libwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/). I don't have Ubuntu but it looks like you can install it using

sudo apt-get install webp

And then [rebuild ImageMagick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251950/imagemagick-convert-cant-convert-to-webp).

Comment: I had to install `libwebp-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I also used to get this error. I have solve it by run command below.
[rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick#prerequisites)

> sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Please make sure you have install ImageMagick

For my issue is happen on:
Ruby: 2.3.0
OS: AWS Ubuntu 14